# How to Stop Join From Creating Doubles of Objects?

Tags: groups, collada

### Situation

I am trying to import a Collada model with many individual pieces to Blender. I have thus far successfully imported the model, added color to the individual parts, and I am now trying to join the objects into groups to allow for easier manipulation.

### Problem

When I try to use Join, it creates doubles of whatever selection I make all over the model. The doubles appear to link themselves to pieces that are the same type as the parent of the joined group, so wherever else that kind of piece is, another double of the joined model occurs. (Pics for reference: Parent piece is the red cross directly under where it says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in the menu)

[image: Fig 1: Pieces are selected, ready to be joined]

[image: Fig 2: Pieces are joined, but identical groups are created in multiple places]

### End Goal

I want to be able to join pieces together without this occurring, so for example, I want an individual group for the pieces on the right (in the picture) and another for the pieces on the left. I am new to Blender and I am not sure if I am missing something simple or if what I am trying to do isn't quite possible or how I should even start going about solving this. If it helps, I am using the most recent version of Blender.

#### Files

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zafk_p7AWDsxO4HvJfTho2Mws4glOBe9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/